# Listar e Acessar subdiretórios em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções, arquivo, sistema-de-arquivos

Boa tarde galera, estou tentando criar um sistema de gerenciamento de arquivos de texto bem simples, porém em algumas das dificuldades que estou encontrado é acessar e manipular arquivos em subdiretórios. Abaixo eu tenho parte do código para manipulação de pastas.

Estou conseguindo acessar a pasta principal, porém não consigo listar arquivos das subpastas, nem acessar subpastas (e manter o acesso para caso tenho um arquivo eu possa editar o mesmo)

Minha dúvida é como posso acessar um subdiretório e manter ele em acesso para poder editar algo que tenha nele (ou também acessar uma pasta dentro desta subpasta) e ao finalizar, retornar para a pasta principal, e caso chegue na principal o programa finalizar.

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import os
import os.path
import shutil

caminhoPAI = '/Users/proce/Desktop/Explorer'


def title(tl):
    print('=' * 80)
    print(f'{tl:^80}'.upper())
    print('=' * 80)
    print()


def acess_dir(caminho):
    with os.scandir(caminho) as it:
        for entry in it:
            if not entry.name.startswith('.') and entry.is_dir():
                print('\t', entry.name)


def listar_arquivos(caminho):
    with os.scandir(caminho) as it:
        for entrar in it:
            if not entrar.name.startswith('.') and entrar.is_file():
                print('\t', entrar.name)


def menu_diretorios():
    title('Navegando pelo Menu DIRETÓRIOS')
    print('Escolha sua opção: ')
    op = str(input('''
        [mkdir] - Criar diretórios
        [rm] - Apagar diretórios
        [cd] - Acessar diretórios
        [ls] - Listar Arquivos
        [exit] - Retornar/Sair
        Opção: ''')).lower()

    if op == 'exit':
        exit(1)

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
    elif op == 'cd':  # ACESSAR DIRETORIOS
        print('_' * 40)
        acess_dir(caminhoPAI)
        tem = (str(input('Informe o nome da pasta a ser acessada: ')))
        dir_acesso = tem
        if not os.path.exists(dir_acesso):
            j = 'S'
            while j == 'S':
                j = str(input('Pasta inexistente. Deseja tentar outra? [S/N]')).upper()
        else:
            for caminho, pastas, arquivos in os.walk(caminhoPAI):
                for pasta in pastas[:]:
                    if pasta == dir_acesso:
                        caminho = tem
                        os.chdir(caminho)
                        print('Pasta acessada!')
        print('_' * 40)

        menu_diretorios()
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
    elif op == 'ls':  # LISTAR ARQUIVOS
        print(listar_arquivos(caminhoPAI))
        print(os.getcwd())
        menu_diretorios()

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
    else:
        print("Esta opção não está nas alternativas, tente novamente.\n")
        menu_diretorios()


print(menu_diretorios())
```

Desde já agradeço toda ajuda e apoio! Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

O comando `os.chdir()` está mudando o diretório atual do python, porém, quando vai acessá-lo você está usando sempre a variável `caminhoPAI` que não está sendo alterada...

Uma solução (parcial) seria, ao invés de mudar o diretório, manter a variável `caminhoPAI` atualizada:

```
caminhoPAI = caminho
```

Porém, assim você perde a referência de qual a pasta inicial de quando o programa começou. Você pode contornar isso usando duas variáveis, uma para o caminho inicial e uma segunda variável mantendo o caminho atual:

```
caminhoAtual = caminho
```

Use essa variável `caminhoAtual` na hora de chamar as suas funções de `listarArquivos`, ao invés de usar a `caminhoPAI` que é fixa.